# Changing x-axis labels in errorbar plot: no attribute 'get_xticklabels'

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I am trying to plot some data the main plot information is

```
ax1 = plt.errorbar(df1.index, df1['Mean'],
               yerr=df1['SD'], color='black', linestyle='-')
ax2 = plt.errorbar(df2.index, df2['Mean'],
               yerr=df2['SD'], color='grey', linestyle='-')
```

The problem is each data frame index is 5% increments of a whole (i.e. df1 index is 0,5,10...100 as is df2) the result is the plot is trying to cram 40 labels on the x-axis

I have tried a few different approaches but none have worked so far.  For example trying to rotate the labels and reduce font size, e.g.:

```
plt.setp(ax1.get_xticklabels(), rotation='vertical', fontsize=7)
```

returns

```
AttributeError: 'ErrorbarContainer' object has no attribute 'get_xticklabels'
```

I get the same error if I try to alter the x axis of ax1 and ax2  using `tick_params`

I think it may be because the plot is seeing the x-axis as categorical but I'm stumped on how to fix it?

Ideally I would like to just show the 0, 25, 50, 75 and 100% labels for ax1 and ax2, but at this point I'd be happy with just rotating them so they look better.

Comment: You need the handle of the axis, not of the plot. You could use `plt.setp(plt.gca(), ...`. Or you can get the handle when creating the figure: `fig, ax = plt.subplots()`, where `ax` is the handle.

Comment: Thanks for this.  I'm using`plt.setp(plt.gca(ax1.set_xticklabels(rotation=40, ha="right")))` but I am getting the same error message. I assume my syntax is wrong?

Comment: I have upgrade my comment to a full answer to uniquely define the syntax. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are using the handle of the plot (of `errorbar`) and not the handle of the axis. There are two ways to get the handle of the axis:

1. When creating the figure (or axis in fact).
2. At any time you can get the handle of the current axis using `plt.gca()`.

An example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.errorbar([0,1,2], [0,1,2], yerr=[.01,.05,.1])
ax.errorbar([0,1,2], [0,2,4], yerr=[.01,.05,.1])

plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation='vertical', fontsize=7)

plt.show()
```

This would result in:

[image]

If you want the use the handle of the current axis you could also have used:

```
plt.setp(plt.gca().get_xticklabels(), rotation='vertical', fontsize=7)
```

Comment: Many thanks for the expanded description. I suspect like a lot of newcomers, after getting my head around python and pandas I've struggled a little with the syntax of Matplotlib.  Your second suggestion fixed my problem entirely.  Im curious how would the first solution work if I have two ax plots? Is a second `ax1 = plt.subplots()` introduced in the same line or or as a second set of plot information before `plt.show()`  .  Again, many thanks for the help.

Comment: @nick.sculthorpe I have the feeling that you are entangling an axis with a(n) (plot) object. One axis can hold several plot objects, as I have included in my edit. On top of this a figure can hold several axes (subplots), but I have the feeling that is not what you meant?

Comment: Many thanks!  This is exactly what I meant. Im not stacking different plots but placing different lines on the same plot as per your example.  Perfect.  Thanks again.